# Line not drawing on chart

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3.js and I am struggling with getting the line to draw on this chart: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KHhfD

It looks like the data for the lines are correct in the `console.log`, and the `path`s are appended to the dom, but they're not on the chart.

I am sure it is something obvious, I just can't see it.

Comment: +1 Nice clean code, was a pleasure to read. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paths` are there, but they have been blown off the canvas because of [some minor scaling issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#G.27Gugvuntts_and_Vl.27hurgs).

You are not applying the `xScale` and `yScale` to the paths in `setupLine`. The function should read something along these lines:

```js
function setupLine(interpolation, x, xScale, y, yScale){
return d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate(interpolation)
    .x(function(d, i){
        return xScale(d[x]);
    })
    .y(function(d, i){
        return yScale(d[y]);
    });
}
```

Hence, you'll have to return the scales from the `prepareChart` function.